# Check same occurrence of value in Array of Objects, then add another array in first found object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, for example

```
arr = [
  {
    date: "2020-03-20T11:40:07.620Z",
    name: "whatever",
    id: "abc123"
  },
  {
    date: "2020-03-21T11:21:07.620Z",
    name: "whatever1",
    id: "def455"
  },
  {
    date: "2020-03-22T11:54:07.620Z",
    name: "whatever2",
    id: "abc123"
  }
]
```

Actual data is more than this. I've simplified the array.

Here, id is the key which can be same in more than 1 array of objects, for example in 1st and 3rd id is same.

I want to check if more than 1 objects contain the same value (id). If yes, add another array (sameIdArray) in the first object where id is same (1st in this case) and this array will now contain all those objects where that same value (id) was found and remove them from the actual array. The final array structure will be something like this.

```
arr = [
  {
    date: "2020-03-20T11:40:07.620Z",
    name: "whatever",
    id: "abc123",
    sameIdArray: [
     {
      date: "2020-03-22T11:54:07.620Z",
      name: "whatever2",
      id: "abc123"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
    date: "2020-03-21T11:21:07.620Z",
    name: "whatever1",
    id: "def455"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the groupBy functionality. You can group your data by id and use it accordingly.

You can use libraries like underscore or lodash, if using JavaScript